# Three regular expressions

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

1) {w|w w does not end in 01} Give a regular expression:

$$ 1^*0^* $$

2) {w|w w does not contain the substring 110} Give a regular expression:

$$ ((0∪10)^*1)^* $$

3) {w|w contains at least two 0s and at most one 1} Give a regular expression:

$$ 0^*10^*  or \ 10^* or\ 010 \ or\ 000^*1 \ or\ 100\  or\ 0^*∪100^* $$

Do you agree? Thanks.

Comment: 10101010 doesn't end in 01, but 1010 is not of the form 1*0*.

Comment: 1*0* is not equal to 1111111...111000...0000 ?

Comment: No, it is equal to $\{ \epsilon, 0, 1, 00, 10, 11, 000, 100, 110, 111, 0000, 1000, 1100, 1110, 1111, \ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors:

1) $\mathtt{010} \in L_1$ but is not represented by your regular expression.

2) $\mathtt{1101} \notin L_2$, but can be produced by your expression.

3) $\mathtt{1} \notin L_3$, but can be produced by your expression.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: 2) isn't ((0 ∪ 10)*1)* equal to 000...001111...11 or to 10101010...101111..1

Comment: @hello regular expressions are not single strings. They are sets of strings.